# Checking the active window by its name

Tags: win32gui

I find the name of the active window using win32gui and check that this window is currently active, but for some reason, when the "RAGE Multiplayer" window is open, the script does not pass the test. In case of checking window with VSCode returns True , with "RAGE Multiplayer" window it returns False.

```
while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('F3'):
        window = win32gui.GetWindowText(win32gui.GetForegroundWindow());
        print(window)
        if window == 'RAGE Multiplayer':
            startloop = True
            print('Game is open')
            break
        elif window == 'test.py - Visual Studio Code':
            print('window is open')
        else:
            print('close')
```

[active window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywGB0.png)

Perhaps the active game window needs a different approach, I don’t understand. Here is a screenshot of the processes
[Processes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbc6a.png)

Comment: You have a `print(window)` in your code. What does that output when you press F3 in the process?

Comment: If I click in the active window, it displays the following:

`RAGE Multilayer
close`

Comment: Well, that seems to be what you are looking for. Copy and paste that output into where you check for the title.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work, it also displays the name of the window that is being checked and gives the result FALSE

Comment: Understood. Find out the true name of the window with the following:

`win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)`